# Recommended architecture for Tridion installation on cloud

Tags: 2011, 2013, content-delivery, content-manager, upgrade

A Tridion document gives a clear picture when installation is to be done on in-house infrastructure.  Is there any specific documentation available when installation is to be done on cloud?

1. Licensing: Do we need to follow same process while requesting
   licenses? Or we need to explicitly mention that license requested
   will be used on cloud implementation?
2. Server configuration for CMS, CDS and database remains same or
   additional space or memory is required to overcome latency if any?
3. Publisher/Database needs to configure on dedicated machine?
4. As we are upgrading from Tridion 2011 SP1 to Tridion 2013, should
   we upgrade database in our environment and after upgrade put it in
   cloud?
5. What approach should be taken for upgrading Content Delivery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should we consider when upgrading from SDL Tridion 2011 to 2013 and putting our non-production environments on the cloud?](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/6113/what-should-we-consider-when-upgrading-from-sdl-tridion-2011-to-2013-and-putting)

Comment: I am trying to understand how this question is different from the earlier similar question asked by you?

Comment: I have to say that I find this question better suited than your previous one, this at least asks a clear and answerable question, where the other is rather open ended. That being said, I think the cloud stuff could be taken out of your previous question, as it is clearly answered here very well.

Comment: @Pankaj & Bart, I agree with you, but as I had queries about License, approach on upgrade and architecture I raised this new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be totaly same on cloud environment, only thing where you need to put your effort is domain controller for setting up the LDAP otherwise rest is same. and yes need to open few ports between CMS , DB and CD servers.

Usually your architecture vary only for the DTAP environments not wheather you are using cloud or your local servers.

- Dev Environment - can have separate servers for CM, CD and DB each,
- Test Environment - Separate one server each for CM, CD and DB;
- Acceptance & Production - Should be in sync for configuration point of view. Cluster of multiple servers for each CM, CD and DB

Answer for your questions:

1. For licence you need to follow same procedure, need to provide the servers name and cpu counts.
2. No addition space is required.
3. This depends on your DTAP environment and hits on your site.
4. No impact would be in case if upgrade database on cloud.
5. In content delevery server you only install server roles, if you only copy serever roles from your existing server to cloud and do update the licence files, configuration files then it would work.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know things like Amazon RDS and Azure Databases - any Database-as-a-service - isn't supported ... yet. So you'll need to use a virtual machine with one of the Tridion-supported databases on it.

But apart from that, if you provision adequate virtual machines running the correct OS prerequisites for Tridion, the installation is no different to physical kit.

There are probably a few gotchas specific each cloud provider - security, firewalls etc, but the installation process for Tridion should be the same.